# Providing access to unstructured files in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

So I have a collection of files archived in a HDFS with a unique key in the file-name. I have a table of records in a HIVE table with the same unique key.

How would I provide access to the files to other users? I may need to restrict access to certain users.

I was thinking of providing a reference to the files in the hive table.

I could also look at some sort of web interface for searching for an downloading files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive kicks off a MapReduce job (or several) every time you execute a query. A latency introduced by setting up and tearing down a MapReduce job(s) exceeds any acceptable standards for a responsivness expected from a web interface.

I recommend you keep the metadata for the files in a relational database. You would have to have a relational database, like PostgreSQL, to store Hive metadata. I sure hope you are not using default Derby for that!